# Styling the result of a wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a working Wordpress site that uses a specific theme, and I need to use a plugin (retribal) as part of the site which returns a list of performers, but it doesn't integrate with the theme styling at all. What I want is for it to look like the rest of the site. I've checked the plugin and under "How Can I Style Performers" it simply says, "Add “rt-performer-” class to your theme styles.

What I actually want is for the plugin to output based on one of the site templates in use on my site - does that even make sense?

I know I hadn't ought to mess with things I don't understand, but I haven't got a clue what to do with the information above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To put this into perspective: you are requesting free CSS coding services because you don't know CSS and you're not considering learning it. Is this correct?

Comment: Not really. What I was hoping is that someone might be able to explain what it is that I need to look for in order to do it myself.

Comment: You need to understand the basics of CSS. Your goal is to take rules applying to other elements of your theme and apply them to the output of your plugin, based on selectors in the markup of that output.

Comment: Thanks - at least a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @RobSealey I'm assuming some theme styles are being applied as the CSS that is included with the plugin only has four selectors. Because the plugin generates it's own markup the CSS selectors that you've written for your theme might not show up. Especially if they rely heavily on class selectors. The more basic selectors in your theme should still be getting applied, i.e. `h1` styles or even common WordPress template classes that get outputted, i.e. [**`post_class()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class). I would right click and inspect elements you want to style.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I really am out of my depth on this, but yes, the 'text' styling is carrying through, but it's the positioning that's really the problem. The easiest way for me to explain is if you look at http://demowebs.net/birminghamjazzfestival/  and then from the artists menu, just pick any artist and see how that looks (naff) - I just want the artist biog to look like it's part of the rest of the site.